# Bootstrap 4 row align class center class is not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="row align-items-center remember"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" checked>Remember Me
</div>
                    
<div class="row align-items-center">
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn">
</div>
```

It should be showed in the middle instead. Somehow it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are centering the elements without assigning display:flex to the parent.
So you should add d-flex and justify-content-center classes beside row class.

But you can just add "text-center" class as input element is inline

Answer (score 0):

`align-items-center` works for flexbox. You need to make your `div` a flex-box first and also add `justify-content-center` to align child items center on the x axis.

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center remember"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" checked>Remember Me
</div>
                
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn">
</div>
```